# formula in calling cell "sees" formula in called cell instead of value -- why?

Tags: excel, formulas

This doesn't seem like usual behavior for Excel. I've never seen this happen before. I'll try and explain it as best I can.

I have two spreadsheets, SS-A and SS-B. SS-A has a worksheet, WS-source ,and SS-B has a worksheet, WS-dest in which WS-dest pulls data via a couple of formulas from WS-source.

SS-B has another worksheet, WS-final, which pulls data from WS-dest, again, using formulas. For some reason, the result of the formulas in WS-final fail because the formulas in WS-final "see" the formulas in WS-dest instead of the values of the formulas.

The formulas work in WS-dest. When I look at the spreadsheet in WS-dest, I do not see the formulas in the cells, I see the values of the result of the formulas. However, WS-final's formulas, when trying to use those values fail.

How I have come to this conclusion: WS-dest did not used to use formulas. I hand placed the values in the fields. WS-final worked just fine. A few days ago, I started using formulas to extract the data from WS-source instead of hand-jamming it into WS-dest. Prior to this change, WS-final worked fine. Furthermore, for testing purposes, I replaced a couple of test fields in WS-dest from the formulas to hand-jammed values, which the formulas in WS-final worked again. I took copies of the formulas from WS-final and placed them in unused cells of WS-dest, tweaking the cell references to that the formula would work. As a result, I observed the same behavior.

The macro:

```
Public Function sbTextToColumn(srcRng As Range) As Variant
    Dim vData As Variant

    vData = Split(srcTang.Value2, "/")
    ReDim Preserve vData(0 To Application.Caller.Columns.Count - 1)
    sbTextToColumn = vData
End Function
```

This is a function that another SO member assisted me with and it works great! I personally am a Linux/Unix guy strong in languages like Perl and PHP. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: What Excel version, do you have any macros running? is there anywhere that you can post your file on the net?

Comment: Excel 2007. Macros exist! Unfortunately, I can't post this project for many reasons, but the most difficult is because it's on a separate network separate from the Internet. What kind of situation with macros could cause this kind of problem?

Comment: Jim, do any of the macros run on the data in `WS-final`?

Comment: Could you show us some examples of the formulas that doesn't work (within the whole chain WS-Source / WS-Dest / WS-Final). To be sure, please check none of your cells are formatted as `Text` (one never knows)

Comment: @brettdj @jmax Yes. They do.In fact, there's an array formula in WS-dest that gets propagated from WS-source and it's embedded in a formula in WS-dest. The formula looks something like: `{=substitute(substitute(substitute(myFunction(),"N/A","NA"),"I/R","IR")," ","")} (braces placed to show it's an array formula).

Comment: can you pls post the VBA for `myFunction`?

Comment: @brettdj I've placed it in the OP.

Comment: Problem could be your custom function using the Value2 instead of the Value property. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182812/en-us for differences.

Comment: @cmmi That was the problem. If you place that as the answer, I'll give you the credit! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @cmmi hmm, seems like I might have spoken too quickly...
I have a `countifs()` that I'm using in WS-final that is still seeing the formula (see the SUBSTITUTE formula in my previous response) as the contents of the cells. It's ignoring the values and counting the formula. Very frustrating!

Comment: Is it possible that the embedded macro-function inside the substitute array(s) is the problem. Or in other words, is the fact that these values are placed in an array an issue?

Comment: @Jim, did you check what happens without the array formula? I am not really accustomed to using array formulas, so I wont be able to help you with the arrays.

Comment: @cmmi I got it figured out, finally. Part of the problem was exactly what you suggested with using Value instead of Value2. The other part was that the date column was using both short dates and timestamp dates and my formula was failing because it was looking for short dates with no timestamps. Once I fixed that issue, all was well with the world.

Comment: @Jim good to here you could fix it. Excel does not always make life easier ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem could be your custom function using the Value2 instead of the Value property. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182812/en-us for differences.